# Display data in stacked form in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

Hi I want to display data in stacked form i.e one after the other in 2 coloumn format. I am using below code for that. But I am getting spaces between the data as shown in attachment;[image] if data is more in one component and less in another.

```
 <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
       <aura:iteration items="{!v.body}" var="test">
           <lightning:layoutItem size="6" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="6">
               {!test}
           </lightning:layoutItem>
       </aura:iteration>
   </lightning:layout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how an SLDS grid (lightning:layout) works. If you want to have them immediately below each other, you'd have to make a left grid and right grid:

```
<lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
    <lightning:layoutItem size="6">
        <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.body}" indexVar="leftIndex" var="test">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!mod(leftIndex,2)==0}">
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="12">
                        {!test}
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                </aura:if>
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:layout>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="6">
        <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.body}" indexVar="rightIndex" var="test">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!mod(rightIndex,2)==1}">
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="12">
                        {!test}
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                </aura:if>
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:layout>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it did not work@sfdcfox

Comment: @Akhil I had to fiddle with the syntax, and I have this working in my developer org. Try the newer version.